# Are deleted 'Hide My Email' addresses reused ever?

Tags: icloud, email

I'm starting to use 'Hide My Email' on pretty much every account that's not, for example, a utility company and while I'm loving the service I'm unable to find details about what happens when you delete an address -- are they reused or does Apple kill those forever?

I do see questions like this one about what happens when you cancel iCloud+:

[What happens to Hide My Email emails if you cancel iCloud+?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428153/what-happens-to-hide-my-email-emails-if-you-cancel-icloud)

In my mind it makes sense that if you quit paying you lose access - however - my question is what happens when you choose to delete an alias that you generated, do those emails get put back into circulation?

In otherwords, when you generate a Hide My Email account is it attached to you forever? Apple's documentation says it's 'Unique to you' but it's unclear what that means in detail to me.